# Version of Ubuntu for SugarCRM

Tags: versions

I have a Windows XP PC I want to convert to Ubuntu and install SugarCRM on.  Not for productive use just for learning.  Do I need a server edition of Ubuntu, or can I just use a Desktop edition? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this on a desktop or a server install of Ubuntu.

You will need to set up an appropriate webserver environment, the easiest would be apache, php, mysql and then you can use that environment to install SugarCRM locally.

All you have to do for adding the LAMP stack is in a terminal run the following

```
sudo apt-get install tasksel
sudo tasksel install lamp-server
```

This will make sure that you have tasksel installed and that it installs Apache, PHP, and MySQL.

From there you can download the SugarCRM software into your web root directory (usually /var/www/html) and then set-up your database and follow the SugarCRM installer.